# What's the regex for removing dots in acronyms but not in domain names?

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove dots in acronyms but not in domain names in a python string. For example, 
I want the string

```
'a.b.c. test@test.com http://www.test.com'
```

to become

```
'abc test@test.com http://www.test.com'
```

The closest regex I made so far is

```
re.sub('(?:\s|\A).{1}\.',lambda s: s.group()[0:2], s)
```

which results to

```
'ab.c. test@test.com http://www.test.com'
```

It seems that for the above regex to work, I need to change the regex to

```
(?:\s|\A|\G).{1}\.
```

but there is no end of match marker (\G) in python.

EDIT: As I have mentioned in my comment, the strings have no specific formatting. These strings contain informal human conversations and so may contain zero, one or several acronyms or domain names. A few errors is fine by me if it would save me from coding a "real" parser.

Comment: IMHO a regex is not the right tool for your problem. It might be possible but leads to overly complex code. I would employ a more traditional approach and use a mix regexs and python code to split the string into its components (normal text, acronyms, ...) and process the parts indivually. More verbose but also more maintainable.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I'm using this as part of a series of other regex's to normalize a sequence of strings representing informal human conversations. I can tolerate a few errors if that would save me from doing a more thorough parsing.

Comment: You need to specify the problem better. Is your data always in three space separated parts, and you only want to affect the first part? Or do you need to apply this to arbitrary text? If the later, how would you define an acronym? Only single letters? If so, what do you expect to happen with http://a.b.example.com? Or is it that you want to remove embedded periods except when you know it is part of a domain name? But that only begs the question: When is it part of a domain name: After @ or http://? What about ssh: or other URL schemes? Once defined, any of these would be an easy regex.

Comment: After some more thinking, what I really want is to remove dots corresponding to an acronym only. I define an acronym as a sequence of single alphabetic characters followed by a dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me (with thanks to Bart for his answer):

```
re.sub('\.(?!(\S[^. ])|\d)', '', s)
```

This will not remove a dot if it is the first character in a word or acronym.

Answer (score 5):

If your data is always formatted like this then why not split your data into 3 parts by splitting on the space.

Then it's pretty trivial to remove the periods from the first element and use join to remerge the parts.

Comment: It's not always formatted like this. I will be using it on informal human conversations as mentioned in my newly-added comment.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you split the string at '@' (or whatever character makes sense), do the substitution on the first part, then put the string back together. I think that will show the intent of the code better than a complex regexp. Something like this, perhaps:

```
string='a.b.c. test@test.com http://www.test.com'
left, rest = string.split("@",1)
left = left.replace(".","")
result="%s@%s" % (left, rest)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply remove DOTS that don't have two [a-z] letters (or more) ahead of them:

```
\.(?![a-zA-Z]{2})
```

But that will of course also remove the first DOT from the following address:

name.i@foo.bar

You could fix that by doing:

```
\.(?![a-zA-Z]{2}|[^\s@]*+@)
```

but I'm sure there will be many more such corner cases.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. This was the basis of my answer. It did come to my mind before but I'm mistaken in not pursuing it.

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex way:

```
>>> S = 'a.b.c. test@test.com http://www.test.com'
>>> ' '.join(w if '@' in w or ':' in w else w.replace('.', '') for w in S.split())
'abc test@test.com http://www.test.com'
```

(Requires spaces to split on, though - so if you had something like commas with no spaces it could miss some.)

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as a simple `re.sub()`, but try this:

```
import re

s='a.b.c. test@test.com http://www.test.com'
m=re.search('(.*?)(([a-zA-Z]\.){2,})(.*)', s)

if m:
    replacement=''.join(m.group(2).split('.'))
    s=m.group(1)+replacement+m.group(4)

print s
```

It assumes that there's no more than one acronym per string, but you could always run it repeatedly.